# Find $\{x\in \mathbb R\colon\neg(3x>21\implies x\leq 5) \}$

Tags: logic

For which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ does $\neg(3x>21\implies x\leq 5)$ hold?

I believe it holds for all $x>7$, but I don't know how to formally write this down.

Can someone help me out? Is there a systematic way of doing this?

Comment: Get rid of $\neg$ and $\implies$ and convince yourself of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

your statement is equivalent to
$$
\neg((x \gt 7)\implies \neg (x\gt 5))
$$
since $\neg(a \implies b) \equiv \neg(\neg a \lor b) \equiv a \land \neg b$ if you substitute the expressions you will see that your belief is well-founded